# Docking station with 3 Display Ports for Linux

Tags: linux, display-port, docking-stations

I have MSI GV62 8RC with Linux Mint 19 installed. It has 1 HDMI port and 1 miniDP which works mostly ok (sometimes I have to unplug and plug miniDP again few times to get it working).

But now I would like to one additional display which leads me to searching for docking station.

Could you suggest me something for my config?
The best would one with 3 Display Ports so I could just plug docking station to get it all work.

Answer (score 1):

StarTech makes a Docking Station with three Displayport connections:
[Model: USB3DOCKH2DP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012VKW900)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Dell D3100 works well with 3 displays (also other features of docking station works well).
But note all displays work with max 1920 (I had to connect my 29" display directly to laptop hdmi port)

Comment: Unless you purchase a 4K docking station, 1920 is the expected max resolution. You must also pair it with a 4K monitor and a GPU capable of pushing 4K. Which dock did you end up purchasing?

Comment: Dell D3100 - in spec I saw it is capable of handling 3 display including one 4k. Unfortunately in my configuration it does not work in 4k - all in 2k. That is why I end up with connecting 29" 4k display directly to laptop hdmi slot

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't get it to push 4K on one of the monitors, but I'm glad your workaround solved the issue!